# Como Pegar Resultados Próximos a um Específico

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando pegar resultados próximos a um registro específico.
Tentei usar o ABS, mas não consegui fazer usando ele.
**O limite de resultados é 5**.

#### Dados

```
MARCA   NOME_MARCA          MEDIA
8       TOYOTA              100
11      HONDA               100
5       FORD                100
10      CHEVROLET           0
6       FIAT                -100
4       VOLKSWAGEN          -100
```

Eu tenho esses dados acima. Gostaria de fazer uma consulta que me retornasse os dois próximos e os dois anteriores. Por exemplo, o usuário é a FORD. Quero que me retorne numa consulta o seguinte:

```
MARCA   NOME_MARCA          MEDIA
8       TOYOTA              100
11      HONDA               100
5       FORD                100
10      CHEVROLET           0
6       FIAT                -100
```

A FORD está no meio por coincidência. Mas se for a FIAT, quero que mostre assim:

```
MARCA   NOME_MARCA          MEDIA
5       FORD                100
10      CHEVROLET           0
6       FIAT                -100
4       VOLKSWAGEN          -100
```

Ou seja, quero que sempre apareça a marca que eu levar como parâmetro, os dois anteriores (se tiver) e os dois próximos (se tiver).

Meu SELECT está um pouco grande, porquê é um cálculo que faço. Mas vou postar abaixo:

```
SELECT
 `empresas`.`id_marca` AS `id_marca`,
 `brands`.`marca` AS `marca`,
sum(`pro`.`qtd_pro`) AS `qtd_pro`,
sum(`det`.`qtd_det`) AS `qtd_det`,
sum(`neu`.`qtd_neu`) AS `qtd_neu`,
round(
    (
        (
            (
                sum(
                    COALESCE (`pro`.`qtd_pro`, 0)
                ) - sum(
                    COALESCE (`det`.`qtd_det`, 0)
                )
            ) / (
                (
                    sum(
                        COALESCE (`pro`.`qtd_pro`, 0)
                    ) + sum(
                        COALESCE (`neu`.`qtd_neu`, 0)
                    )
                ) + sum(
                    COALESCE (`det`.`qtd_det`, 0)
                )
            )
        ) * 100
    ),
    0
) AS `nps`
FROM
(
    (
        (
            (
                 `empresas`
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT
                         `empresa_ratings`.`id_empresa` AS `id_empresa`,
                        COALESCE (
                            count(
                                 `empresa_ratings`.`rating_nps`
                            ),
                            0
                        ) AS `qtd_pro`
                    FROM
                         `empresa_ratings`
                    WHERE
                        (
                             `empresa_ratings`.`rating_nps` >= 9
                        )
                    GROUP BY
                         `empresa_ratings`.`id_empresa`
                ) `pro` ON (
                    (
                        `pro`.`id_empresa` =  `empresas`.`id`
                    )
                )
            )
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                     `empresa_ratings`.`id_empresa` AS `id_empresa`,
                    COALESCE (
                        count(
                             `empresa_ratings`.`rating_nps`
                        ),
                        0
                    ) AS `qtd_det`
                FROM
                     `empresa_ratings`
                WHERE
                    (
                         `empresa_ratings`.`rating_nps` <= 6
                    )
                GROUP BY
                     `empresa_ratings`.`id_empresa`
            ) `det` ON (
                (
                    `det`.`id_empresa` =  `empresas`.`id`
                )
            )
        )
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT
                 `empresa_ratings`.`id_empresa` AS `id_empresa`,
                COALESCE (
                    count(
                         `empresa_ratings`.`rating_nps`
                    ),
                    0
                ) AS `qtd_neu`
            FROM
                 `empresa_ratings`
            WHERE
                (
                     `empresa_ratings`.`rating_nps` BETWEEN 7
                    AND 8
                )
            GROUP BY
                 `empresa_ratings`.`id_empresa`
        ) `neu` ON (
            (
                `neu`.`id_empresa` =  `empresas`.`id`
            )
        )
    )
    JOIN  `brands` ON (
        (
             `brands`.`id` =  `empresas`.`id_marca`
        )
    )
)
WHERE
(
    (`pro`.`qtd_pro` IS NOT NULL)
    OR (`det`.`qtd_det` IS NOT NULL)
    OR (`neu`.`qtd_neu` IS NOT NULL)
)
GROUP BY
   `empresas`.`id_marca`
ORDER BY
   nps desc
```

Comment: Penso que poderia ter um índice e você seleciona os itens cujos índices são >= indice item procurado menos 2 e <= indice item procurado mais 2

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo Mas eu teria que fazer 3 Selects ou apenas 1 ?

Comment: Apenas um se ao montar o select principal você já souber o índice do item procurado. Se não dois. Ou um principal com um sub select.

Comment: Não consigo colocar em código o que você está falando...

Comment: Como não? Digamos que na sua tabela tenha os índices, e que o indice de FORD seja 5. Se você souber de antemão então ficaria assim:  ´SELECT MARCA, NOME_MARCA, MEDIA FROM TABELA WHERE INDICE >= ( 5 - 2 )  AND INDICE <= ( 5 + 2 )´ ou assim  ´SELECT MARCA, NOME_MARCA, MEDIA FROM TABELA WHERE INDICE >= ( SELECT INDICE - 2 WHERE MARCA = 'FORD' )  AND INDICE <= (  SELECT INDICE + 2 WHERE MARCA = 'FORD' )´

Comment: Eu sou burro. Esse índice a que você se refere é o ID único do registro ou é outra coisa ?

Comment: Sim, pode ser, ou um outro qualquer cuja regra de negócio os coloque  próximos uns aos outros.

Comment: Não dá para ser o ID porquê o ID pode pular.

Comment: Coloque outro. E coloque os próximos seguindo uma regra lógica para que apareçam no mesmo select.